# Subclass UIImage imageNamed:?

Tags: ios, image, cocos2d-iphone, iphone-5

I am on my voyage to supporting the iPhone 5. I am well aware that there is iOS 6's auto layout feature in Interface Builder. This is great however, sometimes I want to load my own images if its an iPhone 5.

So some of the images in my game for iPhones are exactly the screen's size either (320x480) or (640 x 960). So if I am on an iPhone 5 those images will not cover the entire screen. So I am going to make (640 x 1136) images for those full screen images.

Now I know that if I simply name the image: MyImage-568h@2x.png it won't load. So, how would I subclass UIImage so that it will load the -568h@2x image thats not the default image?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The lazy way:

   ```
   UIImage * img = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height > 500 ? [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-568h.png"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];
   ```

   I've done this in an app where the main screen on devices without a camera is `Default.png`; it doesn't seem *too* hacky because we would need to change Default.png to support new devices anyway.
2. The less lazy way: Condition on the space you need to fill, *not* the screen size.
3. The solution you asked for isn't really generic enough to warrant a class, but here it is anyway:

   ```
   @implementation MyImage
   +(UIImage)imageNamed:(NSString*)name {
     if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height > 500) {
       UIImage * img = [UIImage imageNamed:[name stringByAppendingString:@"-iPhone5"];
       if (img) { return img; }
     }
     return [UIImage imageNamed:name];
   }
   @end
   ```

   There's really no need to subclass UIImage. If you're feeling *really* hacky, you can patch/swizzle/otherwise `+[UIImage imageNamed:]` to point to a custom method, but I really don't recommend that except for debugging.

Comment: The issue with #1 is that my app also supports iPad so that will result in returning the wrong UIImage. I am not a big fan of #2 but it is a possibility. #3 seems good except for #1's issue, also the only reason I asked about a subclass if because I will be load iPhone 5 custom assets in multiple views so I would just call one shared method. If there is a way #1 can work without that issue, ill go that route.

Comment: If the screen's taller than 700 pixels, it's an iPad! Or you can condition on `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` too.

Comment: I'm confused. For UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM, that will only return if it is a iPhone or iPad and thats it. It won't tell me if its an iPhone 5. I am still confused about checking via the bounds.height.

Comment: `bool isiPhone5 = (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && [UIScreen mainScreen].bound.height > 500);`

Comment: Gotcha that makes sense, but doesn't the iPhone 5 have a specific height in points that I can check for just to make shorter code?